# trouble understanding time conversions

Tags: python, time, epoch, datetime-conversion

I have some trouble understanding time conversions in python.
I have two identical `time_struct` objects

```
In [22]: local_dt
Out[22]: datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
In [23]: local_dt.timetuple()                                                                                                                             
Out[24]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2000, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=0)
```

When I feed it to the `time.mktime` function on one machine

```
time.mktime(local_dt.timetuple())
```

it returns `946681200.0`

On a second machine I get a different answer

```
In [31]: local_dt.timetuple()                                                                                                                             
Out[31]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2000, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=0)

In [32]: time.mktime(local_dt.timetuple())                                                                                                                
Out[32]: 946684800.0
```

The machines have different timezones, though:

```
In [44]: time.tzname                                                                                                                                      
Out[44]: ('Europe', 'Europe')

In [45]: time.tzname
Out[45]: ('CET', 'CEST')
```

The documentation on the time module says:

> Use the following functions to convert between time representations:
>   struct_time in local time seconds since the epoch mktime()

As I understand my local time is "America/Los_Angeles" so seconds since epoch should be exactly the same and not be depending on the system configuration.

What am I misunderstanding? How do I have to calculate the timestamp correctly then?

Comment: The delta between the two values is exactly 3600 seconds (one hour), which smells to me like a Daylight Savings Time issue. That said, it looks like they are set up the same, so I'm not sure why this delta exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`time.mktime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime) interprets the `timetuple` based on the local machine's timezone.  Notice how your `timetuple` object doesn't contain any timezone info, so the timestamp created will always vary based on timezone set on the local machine.  Thus it's entirely understandable why the same `time.mktime(local_dt.timetuple())` returns different value on those two machines.

You can use [`local_dt.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.timestamp) instead, while both are [essentially the same](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.dhttps://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.timestampatetime.timestamp)...

> Naive `datetime` instances are assumed to represent local time and this method relies on the platform C `mktime()` function to perform the conversion.

... But since you're creating the `timestamp` directly from the non-naive `datetime` object, it still retains the timezone info and can shift the time accordingly:

> For aware `datetime` instances, the return value is computed as:
>
> `(dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)).total_seconds()`

Observe:

```
>>> est = datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 31, 19, 0).astimezone(pytz.timezone('EST'))
>>> utc = est.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))
>>> est
datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 31, 19, 0, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'EST'>)
>>> utc
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> est.timestamp()
946684800.0           
>>> utc.timestamp()
946684800.0           # same as est
>>> time.mktime(est.timetuple())
946684800.0
>>> time.mktime(utc.timetuple())
946702800.0           # different than est
```

The last `time.mktime()` processed `utc.timetuple()` as a local time since the timezone info was not passed.  You can notice it's offset by 18000 (`time.timezone` for EST, my time zone).

Answer (score 0):

As you said : "The machines have different timezones, though:" and doc said: "in local time".

Your "local time" is not the same on both machine : one is Europe/europe (probably GMT, so UTC+0), the other one is CEST (UTC +1).

see https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/eu

> Central European Time (CET) is 1 hour ahead of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). 
>   This time zone is in use during standard time in: Europe, Africa.

I think you want to convert your datetime into "UTC+0 datetime"